# Specify checkpoint path in custom docker image in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker, checkpoint

I am training a model on SageMaker using a custom docker image.
I need to specify the local path (the one in the container) used to store checkpoints, so that SageMaker can copy its output to S3.
According to the documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-checkpoints.html , I can do that when I initialize the Estimator:

```
# The local path where the model will save its checkpoints in the training container
checkpoint_local_path="/opt/ml/checkpoints"

estimator = Estimator(
    ...
    image_uri="<ecr_path>/<algorithm-name>:<tag>" # Specify to use built-in algorithms
    output_path=bucket,
    base_job_name=base_job_name,
    
    # Parameters required to enable checkpointing
    checkpoint_s3_uri=checkpoint_s3_bucket,
    checkpoint_local_path=checkpoint_local_path
)
```

I'd like better to specify the checkpoint_local_path within the docker build. Is there a way to do that when building the image? Maybe using an environment variable? This would be also more consistent to what AWS recommend: *We recommend specifying the local paths as '/opt/ml/checkpoints' to be consistent with the default SageMaker checkpoint settings. *

Answer (score 0):

unlike you don't like the `/opt/ml/checkpoints` name, you don't need to specify anything in your docker, apart from writing in `/opt/ml/checkpoints` (and reading from it if you're doing transfer learning or want to pickup from previously saved checkpoints)

Anything you write to `/opt/ml/checkpoints` in your container will be saved in S3 at the location you specify in `checkpoint_s3_uri='s3://...'`